# How to Add Sorting with Method and Array in Java

Tags: java

How to display the most fruit with the name and lots of fruit? Can you help me guys, I confusion to add method with sorting in this code. Thank you :D

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the lots of fruit: ");
        int numberOfFruit = userInput.nextInt();
        String[] fruitName = new String[numberOfFruit];
        int[] lotsOfFruit = new int[numberOfFruit];
        nameAndLotsOfFruit(userInput, numberOfFruit, fruitName, lotsOfFruit);


    }
    static void nameAndLotsOfFruit(Scanner userInput, int numberOfFruit, String[] nameFruit, int[] lotsOfFruit) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFruit; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of fruit " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            nameFruit[i] = userInput.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the lots of fruit " + nameFruit[i] + ": ");
            lotsOfFruit[i] = userInput.nextInt();
        }
    }
    static int theMostFruit(int numberOfFruit, String[] nameFruit, int[] lotsOfFruit) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFruit; i++) {
            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to sort. You are just searching for the index of the fruit with the greatest number of lots. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are holding name and amount informations in 2 different collections thus making it complexer to handle it. There are many ways to do it but I would've done:

1. Key-Value pair with fruit names as key and amounts as value
2. Create a custom class to hold the information

I would go for the second option now

```
public class FruitCounter {
    
    static List<Fruit> listFruit = new ArrayList<>();
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the lots of fruit: ");
        int numberOfFruit = userInput.nextInt();
        nameAndLotsOfFruit(userInput, numberOfFruit);
        theMostFruit();
    }
        
    static void nameAndLotsOfFruit(Scanner userInput, int numberOfFruit) {
                    
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFruit; i++) {
            Fruit fruit = new Fruit();          
            System.out.print("Enter the name of fruit " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            fruit.setName(userInput.next());
            System.out.print("Enter the lots of fruit " + fruit.getName() + ": ");
            fruit.setAmount(userInput.nextInt());
            listFruit.add(fruit);
        }
    }
    
    
    static void theMostFruit() {        
        Fruit mostFruit = listFruit
                .stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparing(Fruit::getAmount))
                .orElse(null);
                
        if (mostFruit != null)
        {
            System.out.print(MessageFormat.format("{0} has the highest amount with {1} pieces.", mostFruit.getName(), mostFruit.getAmount()));
        }
    }
    
    
    static class Fruit
    {
        private String Name;
        private int Amount;
        
        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            Name = name;
        }
        public int getAmount() {
            return Amount;
        }
        public void setAmount(int amount) {
            Amount = amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Please check where I use **stream** inside the method *theMostFruit*. It does the job for me. Altough if you have 2 fruits with the same amount, it would give you only one. I suggest you to handle that case by yourself as a practice with java streams.